# Finding indexes of even numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to find the indexes of the even numbers in this list.

```
messy = [5, 2, 8, 1, 3]
y = [x for x in messy if x%2==0]
f = y[0]
g = y[1]
print(f, g)
>>> 2 8
z = messy.index(f)
zz = messy.index(g)
print(z)
>>> 1
```

`print(y)` outputs [2, 8] and that isn't in the list, and that's why I can't `messy.index(y)`
I'm a bit confused here. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.index` method will fail when there are 2 or more of the same value elements in your list. Instead, you can simplify by enumerating your list and using the indices as follows

```
even_indices = [i for i, elem in enumerate(messy)
                  if elem % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use a `lambda`:

```
>>> messy = [5, 2, 8, 1, 3]
>>> filter(lambda i: i%2==0, messy)
[2, 8]
```

The above will give you the even numbers. Now if you want to get the indexes of those even numbers, two ways to do this are the following:

*Using a list comprehension like so:*

```
>>> [k[0] for k in filter(lambda (i,j): j%2==0, enumerate(messy))]
[1, 2]
```

*or using `map` combined with `filter`:*

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(0), filter(lambda (i,j): j%2==0, enumerate(messy)))
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use functional approach using `filter` function and `lambda` expression:

For python 2.x:

```
filter(lambda a:a%2==0, messy)
```

For python 3.x:

```
list(filter(lambda a:a%2==0, messy))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `list-comprehension` with `enumerate` to get the `indexes` of the even elements:

```
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(messy) if not e & 1]
[1, 2]
```

---

*the `& 1` here is masking the last bit of each number in the list which represents if it is odd (`1`) or even (`0`), we can then just use Python's `not` to flip this and get the desired result*

Answer (score 1):

If you use `numpy`, you can use `np.where`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> messy = np.array([5, 2, 8, 1, 3])
>>> np.where(messy % 2 == 0)
(array([1, 2]),)
```